# Start UiPath Job with Input (string Array) using API

Tags: react-tsx, uipath-orchestrator, uipath-api

How can we pass Array as an input argument when we start a job using API?

**Background:**

I'm working on a react project and with a button click, I want to start a job with inputs.
I know that we can pass an argument as

> "InputArguments": "{\"message\" : \"hello\"}"

I'm populating an array in React and want to pass it to the process as an input argument.
Following is my uipath code

I've tried doing the following in React project

> const messagesList  = ["message1", "message2", "message3", "message"]

> InputArguments: "{\"messages\": \" "+ messagesList + " \"}"

but when I click on the button and the job starts, it gives me the following error

[image]

When I set the argument in orchestrator and start a job through orchestrator, it works fine

[image]

Can someone please help me with it?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution. The list has to be in JSON format
In react it will be like

```
const msg = {   
     messages : [
        “message1”, “message2”, “message3”, “message4”  
     ] }
```

And then use JSON.Stringify to convert it to JSON

```
InputArguments: JSON.stringify(msg)
```